# Can I make QTKit Capture support an IP camera?

Tags: cocoa, macos, video, qtkit

I've got an IP camera - an Axis M1114 - that I'd like to use as a QTKit Capture device. Only DV cameras and the iSight usually appear on this capture menu. Is there any way of getting the IP camera to appear in this list and work with QTKit Capture?

This might not be possible, but if it is, I'd appreciate any pointers at ways of going about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Apple engineers the same question on WWDC 2010. The answer was "No, you cannot make your own QTCaptureDevice". To record video from AXIS IP cameras we have developed our own framework. You can get frames from the camera and write them to a Quicktime movie. You can do it with QTKit, but works better in 32bit Quicktime framework.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the definitive answer! Do you have any tips for a starting point for recording from the Axis camera? The only thing I can find is this plugin for Quartz Composer: http://kineme.net/release/AxisCamera/01 Although Axis seem to have some kind of SDK.

Comment: We did not use any third party components. The simples way to get JPEGs from the camera is through a http connection. Alternatively, you can use streaming video. They describe it pretty good in the documentation how to connect to the cameras and get the data. The point is to get the frames if you use MJPEG access method, or packets of video stream. Once you have got it you can insert frames to the movie.

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforwards. Thanks!